# Problems using Highstock with the data in the x and y axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I´m having some problems when i try to use Highstock in my proyect. For example i´m trying to make a chart "Provincias" x "Raza", the thing is the chart don´t show me all the "Provincias".

[image]

But if i change the type of chart i see al of it

[image]

The js i´m using in the client is:

```
$scope.MultiDataGrafics = function (rs, title, text) {
                $scope.chartConfig5.xAxis.categories = rs.data.categories;
                $scope.chartConfig5.series = rs.data.data;
                $scope.chartConfig5.xAxis.title.text = text;
                $scope.chartConfig5.title.text = title;
                $scope.chartConfig5.loading = false;
            }
```

and i call this function in another function where i ask for the data

```
//Some Code here not important now
else if (value == '43') {
                        $http.get("/Estadisticas/EstadisticasNivelEscolarProvincia").then(function(rs) {
                            $scope.MultiDataGrafics(rs, 'Estadísticas por Nivel Escolar y Provincia', 'Nivel Escolar', 'Provincia');
                        });
```

I post the json to give more data but i assume is ok because in the pie chart show all the "Provincias".

```
{"categories": ["Primaria","Secundaria","Preuniversitario/Bachiller","Técnico Medio","Universitario"
,"Master en Ciencias"], "data": [{"name": "Artemisa", "center": ["30%"], "data": [{"name": "Primaria"
, "y": 0},{"name": "Secundaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Preuniversitario/Bachiller", "y": 0},{"name": "Técnico
 Medio", "y": 0},{"name": "Universitario", "y": 0},{"name": "Master en Ciencias", "y": 0}]},{"name":
 "Camagüey ", "center": ["70%"], "data": [{"name": "Primaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Secundaria", "y": 0
},{"name": "Preuniversitario/Bachiller", "y": 0},{"name": "Técnico Medio", "y": 0},{"name": "Universitario"
, "y": 0},{"name": "Master en Ciencias", "y": 0}]},{"name": "Ciego de Ávila", "center": ["70%"], "data"
: [{"name": "Primaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Secundaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Preuniversitario/Bachiller"
, "y": 0},{"name": "Técnico Medio", "y": 0},{"name": "Universitario", "y": 0},{"name": "Master en Ciencias"
, "y": 0}]},{"name": "Cienfuegos", "center": ["70%"], "data": [{"name": "Primaria", "y": 0},{"name":
 "Secundaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Preuniversitario/Bachiller", "y": 0},{"name": "Técnico Medio", "y":
 0},{"name": "Universitario", "y": 0},{"name": "Master en Ciencias", "y": 0}]},{"name": "Granma", "center"
: ["70%"], "data": [{"name": "Primaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Secundaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Preuniversitario
/Bachiller", "y": 0},{"name": "Técnico Medio", "y": 0},{"name": "Universitario", "y": 0},{"name": "Master
 en Ciencias", "y": 0}]},{"name": "Guantánamo", "center": ["70%"], "data": [{"name": "Primaria", "y"
: 0},{"name": "Secundaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Preuniversitario/Bachiller", "y": 0},{"name": "Técnico
 Medio", "y": 0},{"name": "Universitario", "y": 0},{"name": "Master en Ciencias", "y": 0}]},{"name":
 "Holguín", "center": ["70%"], "data": [{"name": "Primaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Secundaria", "y": 0},
{"name": "Preuniversitario/Bachiller", "y": 0},{"name": "Técnico Medio", "y": 0},{"name": "Universitario"
, "y": 0},{"name": "Master en Ciencias", "y": 0}]},{"name": "Isla de la Juventud", "center": ["70%"]
, "data": [{"name": "Primaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Secundaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Preuniversitario/Bachiller"
, "y": 0},{"name": "Técnico Medio", "y": 0},{"name": "Universitario", "y": 0},{"name": "Master en Ciencias"
, "y": 0}]},{"name": "La Habana", "center": ["70%"], "data": [{"name": "Primaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Secundaria"
, "y": 0},{"name": "Preuniversitario/Bachiller", "y": 0},{"name": "Técnico Medio", "y": 0},{"name": "Universitario"
, "y": 2},{"name": "Master en Ciencias", "y": 0}]},{"name": "Las Tunas", "center": ["70%"], "data": 
[{"name": "Primaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Secundaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Preuniversitario/Bachiller", "y"
: 0},{"name": "Técnico Medio", "y": 0},{"name": "Universitario", "y": 0},{"name": "Master en Ciencias"
, "y": 0}]},{"name": "Matanzas", "center": ["70%"], "data": [{"name": "Primaria", "y": 1},{"name": "Secundaria"
, "y": 0},{"name": "Preuniversitario/Bachiller", "y": 1},{"name": "Técnico Medio", "y": 0},{"name": "Universitario"
, "y": 0},{"name": "Master en Ciencias", "y": 0}]},{"name": "Mayabeque", "center": ["70%"], "data": 
[{"name": "Primaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Secundaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Preuniversitario/Bachiller", "y"
: 0},{"name": "Técnico Medio", "y": 0},{"name": "Universitario", "y": 0},{"name": "Master en Ciencias"
, "y": 0}]},{"name": "Pinar del Río", "center": ["70%"], "data": [{"name": "Primaria", "y": 0},{"name"
: "Secundaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Preuniversitario/Bachiller", "y": 0},{"name": "Técnico Medio", "y"
: 1},{"name": "Universitario", "y": 0},{"name": "Master en Ciencias", "y": 0}]},{"name": "Sancti Spíritus"
, "center": ["70%"], "data": [{"name": "Primaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Secundaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Preuniversitario
/Bachiller", "y": 0},{"name": "Técnico Medio", "y": 0},{"name": "Universitario", "y": 0},{"name": "Master
 en Ciencias", "y": 0}]},{"name": "Santiago de Cuba", "center": ["70%"], "data": [{"name": "Primaria"
, "y": 0},{"name": "Secundaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Preuniversitario/Bachiller", "y": 0},{"name": "Técnico
 Medio", "y": 0},{"name": "Universitario", "y": 0},{"name": "Master en Ciencias", "y": 0}]},{"name":
 "Villa Clara", "center": ["70%"], "data": [{"name": "Primaria", "y": 0},{"name": "Secundaria", "y":
 0},{"name": "Preuniversitario/Bachiller", "y": 0},{"name": "Técnico Medio", "y": 0},{"name": "Universitario"
, "y": 0},{"name": "Master en Ciencias", "y": 0}]}]}
```

The initial chart config is:

```
    $scope.chartConfig5 = {
                    options: {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'bar'
                        }
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{}],
                    title: {
                        text: 'Estadísticas por Raza y Sexo'
                    },
                    loading: true};
```

Comment: Need a lot more info. It is not clear what it is that the first chart is supposed to be showing, or what is wrong with it. Need to see your chart config; need to see your JSON, regardless of whether the pie chart shows it properly.

Comment: The problem is this: in the pie chart i see all the 14 "Provincias" but in the bar chart i can see only 6. is the same json i dynamically change the type in the view.

Comment: Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to create a live example of the issue (e.g. on jsfiddle). Instead of ajax you can hardcode the data.